# Accessing 'this' scope variable from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose

I am a javascript newbie, i have a problem with the following code. Am trying to set a price value from callback, but isn't working... Any help please?

```
PreInvoiceSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

//Seperating code from state
var codestate = addr[2].split(/[ ,]+/);
this.customer.zipcode = codestate[2];
this.customer.state = codestate[1];

//Calculating base price
if (this.order_subtype == "Upgrade") {
    this.price = 30;
} else {
    this.price = 50;
}
var self = this;

for (var j = 0; j < this.work.length; j++) {

    Price.findOne({
        "item": self.work[j].workproduct
    }, function(err, val) {
        if (self.work[j] != undefined) {
             self.work[j].workprice = 300; <-- this doesn't work
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the value of `j` wont stay like that.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, the closure gets the last value of j. so if the iteration runs from 0 to 3 then you always have self.work[3].workprice = 300; (try tracing).

try working with a library li [lodash](http://lodash.com) and turn you code into something like this:

```
_.each(this.work, function(item) {
    Price.findOne(
        { "item": item.workproduct }, 
        function(err, val) {
            // item.workprice ...
        }
    );
});
```

also, if this is the real code then it's missing a '}' before the last ')'.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var j = 0; j < this.work.length; j++) {
    (function(i) {
        Price.findOne({
            "item": self.work[i].workproduct
        }, function(err, val) {
            if (self.work[i] != undefined) {
                 self.work[i].workprice = 300; <-- this doesn't work
            }
        });
    })(j);
});
```

Comment: also, even though your code works, i think the functional (my) way is more elegant the imperative (your) one. less space for errors.

Comment: Thanks guys, ill try the 'lodash' approach, but the main problem is writing on the context variable..., even when i do var self = this, it isn't assigning the new value to the variable...

Comment: Typo! Yes, but the *functional* way needs a library for just too few lines of code, it is not necessary imo :)

Comment: i agree. if you're doing it once or twice... :)

Comment: it still doesn't work:

 `_.each(this.work, function(item) {

  Price.findOne({
   "item": item.workproduct
  }, function(err, val) {
   console.log(item.workprice); //<--- this is '0' 
    item.workprice = 300;
  });
 });`

When i check the DB, this.work[x].workprice <-- is still '0' :(

Comment: @darioherrera, i think you don't see the assignment because it always assigns to the last value of j. this is why LightStyle wrapped the code with a function.

Comment: @pl47ypus i tried passing the 'j' value, but didn't workout, even if i do self.work[0].workprice = 300, dont work :(

Comment: i assume you're using mongoose. try listening for errors on the connection: connection.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

Comment: @pl47ypus i have a next(); at the end of the function... save() is also needed?

Comment: if you change a document then i believe that's what you need to do. it's hard to say since i don't understand the full context